# Unexpected error. Unimplemented Command: xpath locator strategy is not supported'

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath

This issue occurring in desktop automation framework with C# and NUnit with WinApp Driver

I have tried changing locator and also applied explicit waits. Used Inspect Object to find the XPath.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeZqS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhOj4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KdO4.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
(By.XPath($"//MenuItem[starts-with(@Name, \"Add Subsystem Folder...\")]"))
```

Above code seems to be incorrect.

The double slashes(`//`) should be followed by a `<tag name>`, and `MenuItem` is not a tag name. Refer the below code:

```
By.XPath($"//<tag name>[starts-with(@Name, 'Add Subsystem Folder...')]")
```

Replace `<tag name>` with the actual tag name. For example, if the tag name is `<div>`, change the code as `//div[starts-with.....`